# How can I send user credentials for use on a remote machine using WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services, permissions

I have two machines, we'll call them machine A and machine B. Machine B is running a Windows service written in C#.net, as the Local System account. Machine A tells machine B's service (using WCF) to open a file located on the network. Since local system is not a network user, it does not have access to network files, and is unable to open the file. Currently, I am reading files from machine A and serializing them as strings to machine B, and then writing them locally on B. I've considered making a generic network account for machine B, so it can have access to the network, however this is undesirable. Is there any way I can make machine B open files using the user account of machine A? I've taken a look at the system security principal's identity classes, would this be a case to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN - How to: Impersonate a Client on a Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731090.aspx)

> Impersonating a client on a Windows
>   Communication Foundation (WCF) service
>   enables the service to perform actions
>   on behalf of the client. For actions
>   subject to access control list (ACL)
>   checks, such as access to directories
>   and files on a machine or access to a
>   SQL Server database, the ACL check is
>   against the client user account

Also don't forget to configure your service to use Windows Authentication and use a supported binding.

Comment: Okay, looks like I've got it mostly working, however when I check client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredentials.UserName it appears to empty. It looks like this isn't getting my credentials from Active Directory, but everything else appears to behaving as it should.

Comment: @MGSoto, ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredentials.UserName is not for retrieving client credentials, but for supplying a different set of windows credentials if necessary (basically a set only property), to get the current user use Environment.UserName or System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.UserName...but there are other ways also

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I was hoping that it would show me what it would consider is the logged in user. Any idea why I still might be getting access denied errors? I'm pretty much following MSDN word for word, the only difference is instead of adding numbers, I'm opening a file.